# Align center dropdown-menu Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to align my dropdown menu to the center, I'm using Bootstrap 4.

I'm following this example:

[[image: Example Dropdown Menu]]

And this is what I'm getting:

[[image: My situation]]

This is my code:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md pl-4 user-dropdown text-center">
      <div class="dropdown btn-group">
        <a class="navbar-brand dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="bd-versions" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li>
            <a href="{{ route('logout') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('frm-logout').submit();">
                                        Logout
                                    </a>
            <form id="frm-logout" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
              {{ csrf_field() }}
            </form>
            <hr>
          </li>
          <li><a href="{{ route('user.profile') }}">My Profile</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md">
      <span><a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></a></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md">
      <span><a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></a></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did my answer solve your issue?

Comment: Excuse me, I hadn't seen your answer. It works, thanks a lot.

Comment: Cool thanks for letting me know :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use this

```
.user-dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  left: 50% !important;
  transform: translateX(-50%) !important;
  top: 100% !important;
}
```

```css
.user-dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  left: 50% !important;
  transform: translateX(-50%) !important;
  top: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md pl-4 user-dropdown text-center">
      <div class="dropdown btn-group">
        <a class="navbar-brand dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="bd-versions" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li>
            <a href="{{ route('logout') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('frm-logout').submit();">
                                Logout
                            </a>
            <form id="frm-logout" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
              {{ csrf_field() }}
            </form>
            <hr>
          </li>
          <li><a href="{{ route('user.profile') }}">My Profile</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md">
      <span><a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></a></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md">
      <span><a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></a></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```